# What are the categories whose objects form a set, called?

Tags: category-theory, terminology, definition

*Small* categories are ones whose objects *and* all the morphisms form sets.

*Locally small* categories are those whose hom-sets are small.

Is there a name for categories whose objects form a set, but not necessarily the morphisms?

Comment: These would be concrete categories I think.   You could still have a forgetful functor into $\textbf{Set}$ from your category $C$ (that defines concrete; I think...), it's just that your morphisms must be encoded as a set map, which is usually always possible.

Comment: @DanielDonnelly the question isn't about categories whose objects are *sets*, it's about categories where the collection of objects is a set. In particular, the objects in $\mathbf{Set}$ do not form a set, since there is no set of all sets.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a specific example you have in mind?

Comment: @varkor This is an **answer** to the question, not a comment. Comments should  be used to **clarify**, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)** for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list; otherwise it will be bumped up periodically. Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup.

Comment: @MPos The motivation was to exercise the axiom of choice while constructing a quasi-inverse to a fully faithful and essentially surjective functor $F$. (But of course, here, we also choose an *isomorphism* $F(G(X))\to X$ for each of the chosen object $G(X)$ whose $F$-image is isomorphic to $X$; so we ultimately need local-smallness as well.)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, there is not an established term for large categories whose class of objects forms a set; certainly there isn't a term in common use. Presumably this is because, while it is easy to come up with artificial examples (e.g. taking small full subcategories of large categories), natural examples are harder to come by.

One way to view these different variants of categories is via enriched category theory. We can speak of *small* and *large* $V$-enriched categories (where $V$ is a monoidal category): a small $V$-category has a set of objects, whereas a large $V$-category has a class of objects. There are two (cartesian) monoidal categories of interest here: the category $\mathbf{Set}$ of sets, and the category $\mathbf{Class}$ of classes. (Exactly how one sets up these definitions depends on one's foundation.)

Then:

- A small category is precisely a small $\mathbf{Set}$-enriched category.
- A locally small category is a large $\mathbf{Set}$-enriched category.
- A large category is a large $\mathbf{Class}$-enriched category.

The concept you mention is the missing combination: a small $\mathbf{Class}$-enriched category. This would be a concise and unambiguous term to use if you need one.